# Allow only HH:mm format for datetime field in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a `Datetime` type field in a model class. But when I want to give any input of `HH:mm` for this field it is not allowed. Only `dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm` is allowed. I want to give input of `HH:mm` format only. I am using database-first approach in Entity Framework.

Comment: if you need hours and minutes only why not using a timespan ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could annotate your model some more:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
public DateTime TimeProp { get; set; }
```

Depending on how you built your view, you may have to do a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a SelectList with the specific times that you want to allow the user to select from, already formatted as 'hh:mm tt', and create a DropDownList with a default value like this:

- Parameter1: DefaultLunch field - model field
- Parameter2: SupportHours list - Select list for Razor DropDownlist
- Parameter3: Selected value upon initial display.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DefaultLunch,

(SelectList)ViewBag.SupportHours, 

Model.DefaultLunch.ToString("hh:mm tt"),

htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @Type = "Time" })
```

On a 'New' entry screen, where the incoming value is empty in the model field:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DefaultLunch,

(SelectList)ViewBag.SupportHours, 

DateTime.Today.AddHours(12).ToString("hh:mm tt"),

htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @Type = "Time" })
```